# run ansible task only if tag is NOT specified

Tags: tags, ansible

Say I want to run a task only when a specific tag is **NOT** in the list of tags supplied on the command line, even if other tags are specified.  Of these, only the last one will work as I expect in all situations:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'not TAG (won't work if other tags specified)'
      tags: not TAG

    - debug:
        msg: 'always, but not if TAG specified (doesn't work; always runs)'
      tags: always,not TAG

    - debug:
        msg: 'ALWAYS, but not if TAG in ansible_run_tags'
      when: "'TAG' not in ansible_run_tags"
      tags: always
```

Try it with different CLI options and you'll hopefully see why I find this a bit perplexing:

```
ansible-playbook tags-test.yml -l HOST
ansible-playbook tags-test.yml -l HOST -t TAG
ansible-playbook tags-test.yml -l HOST -t OTHERTAG
```

Questions: (a) is that expected behavior? and (b) is there a better way or some logic I'm missing?

I'm surprised I had to dig into the (undocumented, AFAICT) variable `ansible_run_tags`.

---

Amendment: It was suggested that I post my actual use case. I'm using ansible to drive system updates on Debian family systems.  I'm trying to notify at the end if a reboot is required **unless** the tag `reboot` was supplied, in which case cause a reboot (and wait for system to come back up).  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
- name: check and perhaps reboot
  block:
  - name: Check if a reboot is required
    stat:
      path: /var/run/reboot-required
      get_md5: no
    register: reboot
    tags: always,reboot

  - name: Alert if a reboot is required
    fail:
      msg: "NOTE: a reboot required to finish uppdates."
    when:
      - ('reboot' not in ansible_run_tags)
      - reboot.stat.exists
    tags: always

  - name: Reboot the server
    reboot:
      msg: rebooting after Ansible applied system updates
    when: reboot.stat.exists or ('force-reboot' in ansible_run_tags)
    tags: never,reboot,force-reboot
```

I think my original question(s) still have merit, but I'm also willing to accept alternative methods of accomplishing this same functionality.

Comment: Tags are not supposed to be used this way. If you provide `-t TAG` you usually expect that all tagged tasks will be executed and not tasks that have 'not TAG` marks.

Comment: I understand I might be bending the rules of tag usage, but I would have hoped that the first example (`tags: not TAG`) would run every time no tags or any combination of tags EXCEPT `TAG` was specified.  I can give you a specific example of why I would find that useful, if you want.

Comment: Yes, please. Because it seems to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: amended w/ actual use case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For completeness, and since only @paul-sweeney has offered any alternative solution, I'll answer my own question with my current best solution and let people pick / up-vote their favorite:

```
---
- name: run only if 'TAG' not specified
  debug:
    msg: 'ALWAYS, but not if TAG in ansible_run_tags'
  when: "'TAG' not in ansible_run_tags"
  tags: always
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old(ish) question, but I had a similar requirement.

It's probably something best implemented another way ... but ... sometimes it can be useful.

I'd achieve it by setting a fact if the tag IS specified, then outputting the message only if the fact is not set, something like:

```
---
- name: "test task runs only if tag missing"
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: "suppress message if tag given"
      set_fact: suppress_message=yes
      tags: reboot,never

    - name: "message"
      debug:
        msg: "You didn't say 'reboot'"
      when: suppress_message is not defined
```

Comment: I like the thinking, though, and I'm sure this is personal preference, that spreading of the "behavior" across multiple tasks is one thing I tend to fight (tilt?) against.

Comment: sure, don't disagree with that as an aim, but I don't know a way to do it in one task, and this does meet your requirements plus you said "I'm also willing to accept alternative methods of accomplishing this same functionality." :-)

Comment: We do it this way to circumvent missing capabilities when using tags to CONTROL something. And while we doing set_fact along with tags to set flags to control the flow of the play, we try to work against the nature of ansible, which is declarative over imperative. In other words: Doing this is imperative programming, not declaring states.

Answer (score 1):

ansible-playbook has a skip-tags option. The example from the docs is

`ansible-playbook example.yml --skip-tags "packages"`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html

Comment: You provided a solution for skipping tasks with the `packages` tag. OP is instead looking for a way to run a task only if the tags used do not include `packages` or if there are 0 tags used.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @paul-sweeney was the way I got this ansible conditional to work for me.

I had the same requirement as the OP

```
when: "'tc' not in ansible_run_tags"
```

Never evaluated the way I would expect and the task it was a conditional for always ran.

Setting the condition as a fact. such as

```
- name: set deployment flag
  set_fact:
    deployment: true
  when: "'tc' in ansible_run_tags"
```

And using the new conditional to that task

```
when: deployment|bool != true
```

Did work to stop it running, and I didn't have to make changes to tags for the other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we have states for controlling (example: started, restarted, stopped), states for installing (present,absent) and components (webserver, db,...).
Ansible is lacking a good separation of those 3 dimensions and mixing those 3 dimensions in a single tag system is leading to confusion.

For example, if you have a 'webserver' and a 'DB' tag, you want to 'restart' the DB and not the webserver using a 'restart' tag.
But it won't work if the 'restart' tasks of the DB and the webserver are in the same tasks file with the same 'restart' tag as the 'restart' tag will start both the DB and the webserver...

So you will have probably to separate webserver and DB tasks in 2 separate files and use the tag at the level of the include.

Using tags means that you have a tree of options, not a matrix of options.

I like the tag concept but the fact that it is not possible to use it in conditional expressions is making it less appealing.

What I recommend is to declare tags in a role but map them into variables as a first task. So the 'restart' and 'db' tags would become boolean variables in my role and use when: instead of tags: